# mqueue max message size and overhead. Is it higher when messages are smaller?

Tags: linux-kernel, posix, ipc

If I have a POSIX mqueue with a max message size much larger than the size of the average message, is there an overhead ?

e.g. If I open an mqueue with a max message size of 2048 bytes, is there extra work being performed whenever a message with a size of 128 bytes is sent and received ?

I assume there is at least some kind of allocation when you create the queue, but I am willing to pay the memory penalty if there is no computational penalty when sending/receiving.

Comment: Do you in extenso mean overhead in mq_send and mq_receive functions ? Do you mount the message queue virtual filesystem ?